# extract first value from multiple columns

Tags: r, matrix, stata

I am trying to do this in R. It is equivalent to the Stata `egen` function  `rowfirst()`.

Suppose I have four columns as shown below (T1, T2, T3, T4). I want to create a new column (TX) which contains for each row the first element in columns T1:T4.

```
ID T1 T2 T3 T4

A  0  2  4  5
B  .  .  6  5
C  .  8  6  1
D  .  .  .  9

ID TX
A   0
B   6
C   8
D   9
```

Comment: @Jim that's what I thought at first as well, but I think the question is really asking for the first non-missing value in each row.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with `row/column` indexing using `max.col`.  Assuming that the missing values are `.`

```
cbind(df1[1], TX=df1[-1][cbind(1:nrow(df1), max.col(df1[-1]!=".", "first"))])
#   ID TX
#1  A  0
#2  B  6
#3  C  8
#4  D  9
```

If the missing values are `NA`, use `max.col(!is.na(df1[-1]), "first")`

Comment: thanks for your reply! when i run the code you recommend i get two columns- column 1 takes the first non missing value but the remaining cells in the column are empty. column two has the first cell empty and the remaining cells are filled with the SECOND non missing value

Comment: @victoria I am not sure I understand your comment.  This output is based on the example you provided.  Here, I assumed the columns as `character` class

Answer (score 1):

We can use `apply` row-wise and check which values are not equal to "." and select the minimum of them in the row.

```
cbind(df[1], TX = apply(df[-1],1, function(x) x[min(which(x != "."))]))

#  ID TX
#1  A  0
#2  B  6
#3  C  8
#4  D  9
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run a quick loop through your dataframe to get the first element in columns T1:T4

Try this

```
Data <- data.frame(ID=LETTERS[1:4], 
                   T1=c(0,".",".","."), 

                   T2=c(2,".",8,"."), 
                   T3=c(4,6,6,"."),
                   T4=c(5,5,1,9), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

NewData <- data.frame(ID=Data$ID, TX=NA, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

for(i in 1:nrow(NewData)){
  NewData$TX[i] <- Data[i,2:ncol(Data)][which(Data[i,2:ncol(Data)] != ".")][1]
}
```

Hope this helps!